# Vitejs | Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "<path>.svg" is not supported

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm trying to use `react-flagpack` in my project that uses Vite, but whenever I use it i get the following error:

> **Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "node_modules/flagpack-core/dist/flags/cDBuMQWP.svg" is not supported**

Is this an issue with Vite? or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: given the fact that google brings up tons of vite-svg-loader I dont think it works out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of June 14th 2021 it's now supported. :3

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this :

```
npm i --save @originjs/vite-plugin-require-context
```

Then Add `ViteRequireContext` into `vit.config.js` :

```
import ViteRequireContext from "@originjs/vite-plugin-require-context";
export default defineConfig(() => {  
   plugins: [
        ViteRequireContext(),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works? I don't know if it will for react-flagpack;  this is likely a require statement that is breaking the build... I found a solution using [@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs), which I posted [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5308#issuecomment-1010652389).

First install the package:

```
 yarn add @originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs -D

or

 npm i @originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs -D
```

And then, in your `vite.config` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { viteCommonjs, esbuildCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    viteCommonjs(),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      plugins: [
        // Solves:
        // https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5308
        esbuildCommonjs(['react-flagpack'])
      ],
    },
  },

});
```

Then, try loading your file normally. This worked for me using `tiny-react-slider` which was using a `require` statement for a `.css` file

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
"type":"module"
```

from `package.json` worked for me.

My `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import ViteRequireContext from "@originjs/vite-plugin-require-context";


const path = require('path');


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), ViteRequireContext()],

  resolve:  {
    alias:  {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
    },

    extensions:  [
      ".mjs", ".js", ".ts",
      ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json",
      ".vue"
    ]
  }
})
```